# How can end users create bookmarks in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-part

How can end users bookmark their important documents, pages, etc within SharePoint 2013 sites? Are there any web parts for the same?

Comment: Please check this link http://smallbusiness.chron.com/bookmark-sharepoint-51887.html

Comment: Yes,I know about anchoring in SharePoint. I actually wanted to know whether a "one click Bookmark" button  or a web part having such  functionality exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint, users have the ability to follow a site, tags, people and even specific documents. You might have noticed this in the top right corner, below the username.

[image]

Simply clicking the follow button will save the bookmark in your personal site so for this to work, you need to have My Sites configured.

When a user follows a site it will show up on their personal page.

If users would like to follow a specific list or document library and be notified when anything changes, there's the `Alert Me` function.

[Following in SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.office.com/2013/02/21/following-in-sharepoint-2013/#iJxf448O4m7Vafwh.97)

[Follow documents to track them](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Follow-documents-to-track-them-e022c55c-4bf0-4809-8b3a-1da870cf17d7)

[Overview of My Sites in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382643.aspx)

I'm unsure if you can follow a single page OOTB.

Comment: Can you really follow a list? Is it not just sites, people, tags and documents (OOTB)?

Comment: @RobertLindgren Edited my answer and cleared it up a bit. Don't know where i got the idea that you could follow a list from. Bad coffee.. :)